# How can I remove the word " and " from a variable if it exists at the beginning of a string?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, flow, powerapp, powerapps-canvas

I am building a oData filter to be sent from Power Apps to Power automate flow to get items, now based on the selection the query sometimes might start with the word " and ".

So how I can remove this 5 chars if they exists at the beginning of the `varQuery`?

```
Set(varQuery,
If(!IsBlank(EndDate.SelectedDate),"(EndDate1 eq '"& EndDate.SelectedDate&"') ")
&If(!IsBlank(EffectiveDate.SelectedDate)," and (EffectiveDate eq '"& EffectiveDate.SelectedDate&"')")
&If(!IsBlank(SalesProgramID)," and (SalesProgramID eq '"& SalesProgramID.Selected.Value&"')"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula like this:

```
Set(
    varQuery,
    If(
        !IsBlank(EndDate.SelectedDate),
        "(EndDate1 eq '" & EndDate.SelectedDate & "') "
    ) & If(
        !IsBlank(EffectiveDate.SelectedDate),
        " and (EffectiveDate eq '" & EffectiveDate.SelectedDate & "')"
    ) & If(
        !IsBlank(SalesProgramID.Selected.Value),
        " and (SalesProgramID eq '" & SalesProgramID.Selected.Value & "')"
    )
);

If(StartsWith(varQuery, " and "), Set(varQuery, Right(varQuery, Len(varQuery)-5)))
```